# Service slower than page | Ionic 4 | Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

First of all: I am very new to coding in general. Sorry if this question is stupid ^^
I tried to build a simple app in ionic with firestore.
Now i wanted to create some simple services. Now i got the problem, that the service is getting the data after the 
"this.userData = this.userService.currUser" was passed. That meas, i have no data in this.userData.

How to do this correctly? :/

Thanks!

The service:

```
export class UserServiceService {
  public currUser: any;
  private currUserRef: any;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    const currUserId = afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.currUserRef = afs.collection('users').doc(currUserId).valueChanges();
    this.currUser = this.currUserRef.subscribe(data => {
      return data;
    });
  }
}
```

The page:

```
export class EventlistPage implements OnInit {

  private events: Observable<Event[]>;
  private userData;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService, private afAuth: 
  AngularFireAuth, public userService: UserServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents();
    this.userData = this.userService.currUser;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your `Observable` to `Promise` and use `.then()`

So your service will look like this

```
export class UserServiceService {
  public currUser: any;
  private currUserRef: any;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    const currUserId = afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.currUserRef = afs.collection('users').doc(currUserId).valueChanges();
  }
  getDataFromFireStore(){
   return this.currUserRef.toPromise();
  }
}
```

And in your user class

```
export class EventlistPage implements OnInit {
  private events: Observable<Event[]>;
  private userData;
  constructor(private eventService: EventService, private afAuth: 
  AngularFireAuth, public userService: UserServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents();
    this.userService.getDataFromFireStore().then(data => this.userData = data);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, i tried that. Now i get "Cannot read property 'getUserData' of undefined"

Comment: Nvm, it works now. Thanks! But the Data is still no aviable at the time when the page renderes. i wanted to do something like 'ngIf="userData.isAdmin". Any ideas to do that?

Comment: Check if Data is not null by wrapping your entire data with a new div and put ``ngIf=data``

Comment: YEs, it seems like data is null. But i cant explain why. It is definetly the correct "currUserId". The collection is correct too and the document isn't empty

Comment: in your User class move what ngOnInit contains to the constructor and try printing data , What you get ?

Comment: I tried, still nothing. I just noticed, that the debugger dosnt even reach the ".then(data => this.userData = data)". But the "this.userService.getDataFromFireStore()" is getting executed.

Comment: Okay, an aditional .pipe(...) helped. Dont know why thats needed :D But thanks mate!

Comment: .pipe allow you to apply operators such map , select , of , from and many , by the way good luck